# Spaces in Names in Command Line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a small problem.

In my folder if I have the following files

```
Script1.sql
Script2.sql
```

The below code works. However, if I have spaces in the file name like

```
Script 1.sql
Script 2.sql
```

It fails. Can someone assist me in modifying the below to ensure the script captures file names with spaces?

```
@echo off

set /p sname= Please enter the servername:
set /p dbname= Please enter the databasename:

ECHO started the batch process at %TIME%  >output.txt

for %%f in (*.sql) do (
sqlcmd.exe  -S %sname% -d %dbname% -i %%f  >>output.txt


)
pause
```

Comment: think what you are looking for is known as 'escape characters'

Comment: OK, how would I implement this?

Comment: look at some documentation for escape characters: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: What if you use `"%%f"`?

Comment: **C:\>cd Documents^ and^ Settings** would be how to ref. Documents and settings

Comment: Great, thanks the "%%f" worked.

Answer (score 3):

Use double/single quotes around those names. That should be enough to "escape" (not litterally escaping but you get the point) those white spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `^` character to escape spaces. So this should be the solution:

`Script^ 1.sql`

Comment: The problem is that he isn't typing those names in his batchfile (where he could escape the spaces), but they "happen" to be on the filesystem.

Comment: Ah I see, this article could help him out: [http://chrisoldwood.blogspot.nl/2013/06/handling-paths-with-spaces-parenthesis.html](http://chrisoldwood.blogspot.nl/2013/06/handling-paths-with-spaces-parenthesis.html)